# Having trouble embed a swf in swfobject

Tags: flash, swfobject

I'm following the steps here:

http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation

I'm embedding it this way:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>SWFObject dynamic embed - step 3</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
      html, body, #myContent { height:100%; }
      body { margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/swfobject/swfobject.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    swfobject.embedSWF("flash/main.swf?sessionId=psjqbunbdoapfqt1cskggvsdi2", "myContent", "100%", "100%", "9.0.0", "js/swfobject/expressInstall.swf");

    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
  <table style="width:100%;height:100%;">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:350px">
            <div id="myContent">
              <p>Alternative content</p>

            </div>
            <noscript>
                <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"
                        id="main" width="100%" height="100%"
                        codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/current/swflash.cab">
                        <param name="movie" value="flash/main.swf?sessionId=psjqbunbdoapfqt1cskggvsdi2" />
                        <param name="quality" value="high" />
                        <param name="bgcolor" value="#eeeeee" />
                        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                        <embed src="flash/main.swf?sessionId=psjqbunbdoapfqt1cskggvsdi2" quality="high" bgcolor="#eeeeee"
                            width="100%" height="100%" name="main" align="middle"
                            play="true"
                            loop="false"
                            quality="high"
                            allowScriptAccess="sameDomain"
                            type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
                            pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
                        </embed>
                </object>
            </noscript>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </body>

</html>
```

It turns out that the flash content is not visibie at all,why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of all the additional stuff, like the `<table>`, `<noscript>`, CSS etc. Just leave swfobject and the `<div>` (no style attributes, either!) in an otherwise empty HTML construct.

If it doesn't show at all: There is something wrong with your swf, or swfobject doesn't load correctly.

If it does show: Start adding stuff.  First re-enter the style attributes.  Reload.  Go on until your content disappears => you know where your problem is!

Also: I would advise not to put an additional `<noscript>`in there - that's what "alternative content" is meant for.  You should really put something alternative in there, like a picture or text, and link to the flash plugin download page.